# Scala: accessing the value of a json node using jackson fasterxml

Tags: json, scala

Okay, I have a scala method as follows: This program is trying to capture the value in the JSON doc pasted after the Scala code:
This value is in the following element"

```
    "patterns": [
          1
      ],
```

I am not able to capture this value. The patterns key or array has a single number. It does not look like a key. If it is not, what is it and how can I get to it. What is the right method is the JsonNode Jackson API?.

So far I thought the following line of code does the trick.

```
tPolicyNode.findValuesAsText("patterns").asScala.toList
```

Apparently, it does not. If anyone can point out where I am going wrong or give me some pointers, I could accomplish my goal of capturing that value.

```
import java.io._
import scala.collection.immutable.List
import javax.json.Json
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import java.util.Properties

object scalaProgram {

   val patternsPath = Array("tPolicyEntry", "comp", "comps", "patterns")


   //raw json (sample.json)coming in from another method
    def locateJsonValueInTree(rawJson: String) = {
        val rootNode = jsonMapper.readTree(rawJson)
        println("Root Node " + rootNode);

       //invoke method to find out the particular value in the json
       val listContainingValue = findtpEntryPattern(rootNode)
        // derive the value out of the list listContainingValue
       //This is supposed to be the value coming out of the 'patterns node'
      //on inspecting the value in this List, there is NOTHING in it
    }


     def findtpEntryPattern (rootNode: JsonNode): List[String] = {
          println("Entering findtpEntryPattern")
          var tPolicyNode = jn
          for(i <- 0 until patternsPath.length -1) {
             triggeringPolicyNode = tPolicyNode.path(patternsPath(i))
           }
         if(tPolicyNode.isMissingNode) {
           throw new RuntimeException("No node with policy Pattern found.")
         }

         //Return a List of String; but this List contains a single entry
           println("Triggering Policy ID : " + tPolicyNode.findValuesAsText("patterns"))
          //I am trying to capture the value contained in the patterns [ 1 ] //element in the JSON 
         tPolicyNode.findValuesAsText("patterns").asScala.toList

   }
}
```

---

```html
"tPEntry": {
        "action": "Log",
        "comp": {
            "type": "OrComp",
            "components": [
                {
                    "type": "PatternComp",
                    "patterns": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "not": false
                }
            ],
            "not": false
        },
        "ticketInfo": {
            "genTicket": true,
            "tags": [],
            "viewUnseeableIds": [
                {
                    "type": "ApUserGroup",
                    "name": "Admins",
                    "description": "Group for system admins",
                    "admins": [
                        "153"
                    ],
                    "members": [],
                    "id": "04"
                }
            ]
        },
        "notInfo": {
            "genNotify": true,
            "contNames": [
                "me@example.com"
            ]
        }
    }
```